# How can I generate a unique random number each time when I run my application?

Tags: java, random, unique

In my application, i want to generate 9 digit random numbers such that they r unique.
Only one 9 digit random number should be generated each time i run the application and it should be unique. Later i want to save this number along with its associated data in a .txt file so that i can retrive the data associated with this unique number when required.
How should i achieve this?

Comment: Yu could use the file size of your file _before_ you write the new information, and pad it with 0s on the left. In this way, all numbers in that file will be unique.

Comment: check out this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Do you want them to be truly random or truly unique?  You can only have one of these.

If you want them to be truly random, then just randomly pick 9 digits from 0-9 and construct them into your number.  There will be a small chance of a duplication, especially over larger numbers of iterations.  It will be truly random, though.

If you want them to be truly unique, then you have to store every one in a database to ensure there are no duplicates.  If you generate a duplicate, you'll need to regenerate or just increment the number and try again.  If this is what you're looking for, it might be good to try just incrementing the value starting at one.

Comment: +1 for making distinction between random and unique

Comment: I wanted truly unique numbers... Thanks for that! its really simple. i can increment them by one!

Answer (score 13):

For unique number try: `(new Date()).getTime()` it will never be the same unless you are generating multiple number in a sec.

Comment: I don't know who -1'd this, but this is actually a valid point (as long as you don't generate a lot of numbers per second).

Comment: @Roy: Even I'm wondering the same. Why someone has downvoted this.

Comment: -1 This will not generate nine digit random numbers.  It won't even generate random numbers.  It just gets the current time in milliseconds.  How is this anything like what the OP is asking for?  I'm wondering why anyone has upvoted this.

Comment: I did not downvote it, but note that it's just not true that getTime() is guaranteed to return a unique number. This is true only under the assumption that nobody manipulates the clock.

Comment: @Erick: You can easily crop 9 digits from it. its not a big deal.

Comment: @Harry: Those 9 digits aren't guaranteed never to be the same, and they certainly aren't random.

Comment: @Erick: yes they are not random. But in most cases they are unique and thats why stated in answer "for unique number try....".

Comment: Unique and random can't be guaranteed. It is possible to use randomness to get almost uniqueness. But that is no guarantee. Therefore, I'd say it is no problem that it is not random. But, the time is of course easy to guess. That might be a problem in some applications.

Comment: With all due respect, this method really shouldn't be offered as a way to generate anything that may be called "unique" or "random." It doesn't come remotely close to achieving either of these qualities. This really shouldn't be cross-linked into new questions on the same topic, because it truly could send a new programmer in the completely wrong direction. I offer my opinion simply as a concerned citizen and hope it is clear I'm trying to give constructive feedback.

Answer (score 8):

You could combine the Random Class & system time (or a function using system time) e.g.

```
  Random random = new Random(System.nanoTime());

  int randomInt = random.nextInt(1000000000);
```

You could also use some function on the system time e.g.

```
  Random random = new Random(System.nanoTime() % 100000);

  int randomInt = random.nextInt(1000000000);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want a random 9-digit number, try:

```
long number = (long) Math.floor(Math.random() * 900000000L) + 10000000L;
```

However, if you just want an unique number I'd go for using a database instead.

Comment: Hi! I want them to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is a unique identifier, that can never be repeated, this is by definition not a random number.

What you're probably looking for are GUIDs, but these are a lot longer than 9 digits (because the chance on generating the same number twice with only 9 digits is quite large if you look at it from a global scale).

Anyway check this wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier

Edit: to clarify, GUIDs have somewhate of a random nature.

Comment: And one thing to keep in mind: A substring of a GUID is not nuaranteed to be unique.

Comment: true, even a full GUID is not guaranteed to be unique :).